# AIML chatbot not learning from aiml file

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, aiml

I am making a voice-assistant for food ordering in fast-food restaurants. For dialog management tasks I am making aiml chatbot.
This is my std-startup.xml code
'''

```
<!-- Category is an atomic AIML unit -->
<category>

    <!-- Pattern to match in user input -->
    <!-- If user enters "LOAD AIML B" -->
    <pattern>LOAD AIML B</pattern>

    <!-- Template is the response to the pattern -->
    <!-- This learn an aiml file -->
    <template>
        <learn>output.aiml</learn>
        <!-- You can add more aiml files here -->
        <!--<learn>more_aiml.aiml</learn>-->
    </template>
    
</category>
```

BELOW IS MAIN.PY CODE

import aiml
import os

kernel = aiml.Kernel()

if os.path.isfile("bot_brain.brn"):
kernel.bootstrap(brainFile = "bot_brain.brn")
else:
kernel.bootstrap(learnFiles = "std-startup.xml", commands = "load aiml b")
kernel.saveBrain("bot_brain.brn")

## kernel now ready for use

while True:
print (kernel.respond(input("Enter your message >> ")))
'''

After entering a msg which is from output.aiml itself the bot says the msg does not exists
[image]

PLease can someone tell how to fix it.
The bot should generate a response as given in output.aiml file

Here is another example with category
[image]

and here is bot's repsonse
[image]

Comment: Can you post the category that you expect it to match?

Comment: sure, I edited in qs please check:)

Comment: Try removing the period at the end of "Thank You". Do you have one at the end of "Hello" too?

Comment: That doesnt work, tried both ways. With and without period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some interpreters need the patterns to be in upper case. Try this instead:

```
<category>
    <pattern>THANK YOU</pattern>
    <template>
        Bye.
    </template>
</category>
```

Comment: Thank you so much capitalising and also removing periods if any at the end of sentences helped!!!